# How to Disable Whole Form from hook_form_alter?

Tags: forms

I've got a form I want to be disabled when certain criteria are met. According to [the Form API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#form) I thought `$form['#access'] = FALSE;` would be sufficient. But no dice.

Instead, I'm doing this, which feels wrong, plus I get an error, "Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in form_builder()"

```
foreach($form as $key => $element){
          unset($form[$key]);
}
$form['#prefix'] = 'Bad user. Don\'t access this form!';
```

Kind of a big stick approach. What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Drupal doesn't cope with the form being removed in such a way because it is expecting certain things in the form array after you have altered it.

That's why you are getting that error, because [form_builder()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_builder/7) does this:

```
if (!isset($element['#id'])) {
  $element['#id'] = drupal_html_id('edit-' . implode('-', $element['#parents']));
}
```

but you have removed `$element['#parents']` when you looped through unsetting everything, including `#parents`.

If you want to loop through all form elements are remove them the correct way would be to use [element_children()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/element_children/7), which will loop through the keys of child elements but skip properties of the current element.

So to loop though child elements you would do this:

```
// Remove all elements from this form.
foreach (element_children($form) as $key) {
  unset($form[$key]);
}
```

Alternatively you could restrict access like this, which could cause you less side effects if other modules are expecting form elements that you have deleted.

```
// Restrict access to all elements in this form.
foreach (element_children($form) as $key) {
  $form[$key]['#access'] = FALSE;
}
```

If the form is a page though, not in a block or something, then it might be better to use hook_menu_alter() to block it as Shawn said in his answer.

Answer (score 3):

There are many solutions here. One solution is to just disable the submission button:

```
$form['actions']['submit']['#disabled'] = true;
$form['#prefix'] = 'Bad user. Don\\'t access this form!';
```

A more elegant way might be to just disable access to the form altogether. For example, using [`hook_menu_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) to set the form page callback to redirect away from the form.

Comment: None of those work for me. If you disable the submit button, then the form is still visible to the user. Why leave a form that is not functional? Bad practice. My form is embedded on a node that needs to be accessed, so redirect doesn't work, either.

Comment: Just a one option depending on different needs. The way I read it originally made me think it was an isolated form, not a part of the node edit form.

Comment: Word. After refactoring and using drupal_static for efficiency, it became practical to just disable the form based on logic surrounding the form. So basically I'm saying you were right.